# Why Wikipedia article doesn't show up on first page of Google search?

Tags: seo, google-search

I've created an article on polish Wikipedia for the person "[Urszula Jędrzejczyk](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urszula_J%C4%99drzejczyk)" and when I search for term *Urszula Jędrzejczyk* in `google.pl` the article show up on second page. Why is that, and is it possilbe to show up on first place somehow? Does links to that article from other sites matter?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Comment: @JohnConde is there a SE site where I can ask this kind of questions, I was looking at area51, it have SEO site but it was mark as duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is new content, it will still take some time for it to go up. Also, you cannot guarantee it's placement on the first place, as there might be some more relevant content (at least according to google).

Comment: I was wondering because, most of the time wikipedia is on the first place or on first page.

Comment: Yes because Wikipedia is trusted source on Google. But on the same second the article appears on Wikipedia. It takes time. it also depends a lot on the quality of content in other pages. Let's say if you google some company name (e.g. microsoft) it will give you their page, not wikipedia.